how to add custom ssl certificate to curlpp
I have this c++ code:
curlpp::Cleanup cleaner;
curlpp::Easy request;

std::string requestUrl = "https://some.domain/"

request.setOpt(new curlpp::options::Url(requestUrl));

request.perform();

I want to hardcode an SSLcertificate inside my c++ so that curlpp only trusts this certificate and no other
I donlt want to load the ssl key from a file because an attacker could manipulate the file and add his own cert.
My goal is to prevent man in the middle attacks from a user who has full access to the environment. I know that an attacker could simply reverse engineer my application that's why I want to use encrypted strings and code obfuscation.
i am aware that i cant prevent attackers from reading my applications network traffic but i want it to make as hard as possible. i am also open for other approaches.

Are you going to statically link libcurl and libssl? If not, your restriction is trivially circumventable.

yes im linking it statically. i am currently using curlpp which is a libcurl wrapper for c++. should i stick with it because it doesnt have much documentation and i couldnt find anything for my problem in the internet. or should i just switch to libcurl?

Isn't it small enough you can just read the headers and source code?

i dont know what you mean by that tbh

You can read the source code of curlpp and see where you can extend it.
